# Passing input to python script invoked by shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

My shell script invokes a python script like this:

```
python take_user_input.py
```

The `take_user_input.py` script after getting invoked asks for user input, like this:

```
$ python take_user_input.py
Please enter your username: <expects user to enter username>
Please enter your email: <expects user to enter email>
```

It is not possible for me to modify the `take_user_input.py` script as it is part of another package.

**Question:** Is it possible to specify username and email in the shell script, such that it automatically takes those values after it invokes the python script?

Comment: You   need a here document feature https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a here document.

```
python take_user_input.py << EOF
me
me@email.com
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes

```
printf "my_username\nmy_password\n" | python take_user_input.py
```